# How do I make a callback return a variable that is not defined in its scope?

Tags: javascript, callback

I want to store an expression and evaluate that expression in another scope using variables from that scope. I don't know how to carry this out.

I am trying to do this using callbacks.

```
class a {
    constructor(b) {
        this.r = b.a;
        this.h = b.b;
    }
    check(_root) {
        console.log(this.r);
        if(this.r() == this.h) return true;
        else return false
    }
}
function callback() {
    return _root.h;
}
c = new a({a: callback, b: 12});
console.log(c.check({h: 12}));
```

But `this.r()` throws an error saying _root is not defined.

**I want to avoid passing `_root` in the callback for some reason.**

Thank in advance.

Comment: You *will* have to pass it somehow.

Comment: *"...for some reason"*: which? NB: the title is misleading: `_root` is not a global variable.

Comment: @trincot alright, fixed it.

Comment: What about telling us the *reason*? Without an explanation there is no way to know what your constraints are.

Comment: Obviously when a callback *can* return a variable, it means it has access to it, and is in its scope (that is what *scope* means). So the title expresses a contradiction. It's like asking "how can I see an invisible image?"

Comment: @trincot I want to avoid it to achieve the template-like feature. I have a large number of calls to these expression and in fact, I am dealing with recursion with recursive call having its own `_root`. Well, now I guess I have to pass the `_root` variable. This just added to an extra effort.

Comment: @UmakantVashishtha You might want to show us your actual code, or at least an example with such a recursion. Do you want to access the original `_root` or the "own `_root`" when the callback is called from within a recursive call?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want,but maybe you can get some help with those change.

```
class a {
    constructor(b) {
        this.r = b.a;
        this.h = b.b;
    }
    check(_root) {
        console.log(this.r);
        if(this.r(_root) == this.h) return true;
        else return false
    }
}
function callback(_root) {
    return _root.h;
}
c = new a({a: callback, b: 12});
console.log(c.check({h: 12}));
```

Comment: I could do this, but I am trying to avoid passing `_root`.

Comment: @UmakantVashishtha Why do you want to avoid that? It's the proper solution.

Comment: @Bergi I want to avoid it to achieve the template-like feature. I have a large number of calls to these expressions. I am dealing with recursion with each recursive call having its own `_root` which is a part of its parent `_root` and sometimes I need a chunk of parent `_root`. Well, now I guess I have to pass the _root variable.